# Replacing special characters not working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove special characters from a string, but when I export the Pandas dataframe as a CSV, I can still see the special characters.

Does anyone know why that is?

Current Code:

```
document = json.dumps(jfile,default=str)
document2 = re.sub("[“â£$€™]", '', document)
document2  = json.loads(document2)
document2.to_csv("test.csv", index = False)
```

Output (special character still found in CSV file):

[image]

Comment: Try `document.str.replace("[“â£$€™]", '', regex=True)`

Comment: You need to determine the encoding of the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems the pandas Encoding problem. Try to read/load your file with the appropriate encoding.